# Reaching Famous Beaches within Tayrona National Park?

Tags: transportation, colombia

Which is the faster way to reach famous beaches in Tayrona National Park from Baranquilla or Santa Marta? My guidebook is short on details but mentions: Arrecife, Aranilla, La Picina and Playa Cristal. I will be staying in Barranquilla but can easily take the bus to Santa Marta or other jump-off point.

There seems to be a road partly there but then maybe it could take an hour or two of walking. Could one take a boat to one of the beaches? Where would it start and arrive? Approximate costs would be nice to know too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way is to start at Taganga which is just North-East of Santa Marta and take a boat that drops you at the docks on Cabo beach. The trip takes just under one hour and officials are waiting there to collect the park fee and check your bags for forbidden items. Once past that, you are in and already on a beautiful beach. It takes 20-30 mins to walk to each beach further west.

Answer (score 1):

In Rodadero (tourist town 1km from Santa Marta), there are tours that go to Tayrona park, and cost around 10~15USD per person (YMVV, if you bargain you could get better prices).

Comment: That's a good place to start. Would you have any more info? Is there a schedule? (To know when to go there and how long it takes) Is that one way or return? Thanks!

Comment: All buses (chivas) https://www.google.com.mx/search?client=opera&hs=Q4z&tbm=isch&q=chiva+rumbera departs from a point in Rodadero, at morning (9am IIRC), the tour includes return, ticket to the park and lunch (is the same food in all tours, fish, rice and salad). Travel time is around 2 hours